# Second function with same integers doesn't work

Tags: c++, function

I have a task to create 2 functions to calculate GCD and LCM. But I noticed that my second function doesn't work not matter what calculation is there. What am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcd(int number1,int number2);


int lcm(int number1,int number2);

int main()
{

    int number1;
    int number2;
    cout<<"enter number 1: ";
    cin>>number1;
    cout<<"enter number 2: ";
    cin>>number2;
    cout<<"The GCD of "<<number1<<" and "<<number2<<" is "<<gcd(number1,number2)<<endl;
    cout<<"The LCM of "<<number1<<" and "<<number2<<" is "<<lcm(number1,number2)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
    int gcd(int number1,int number2)
    {
        if (number2==0)
            return number1;
        return gcd(number2,number1 % number2);
    }

    int lcm(int number1,int number2)
    {
        return lcm(number2, number1 * number2)/gcd(number1,number2);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> enter number 1: 44
> enter number 2: 121
> The GCD of 44 and 121 is 11
> The LCM of 44 and 121 is
> Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
> ```

Comment: In the `lcm` function you do a recursive call to `lcm`. When will that recursion stop?

Comment: [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants you to explain  the logic of the `lcm()` function

Comment: Perfect time to attach your debugger and step through the program's execution line by line.

Comment: `0xC00000FD` = `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`

Comment: Increase the stack size with `ulimit -s 65536`

Comment: @Jellyboy that's not the real solution. The problems lies within the `lcm()` function

Comment: @Jellyboy increasing the stack limit will just make the program crash later, infinite recursion needs an infinite stack. Plus that command is for linux this is on windows

Comment: I know it's not a solution. If it was a solution, I'd have written an answer. This is just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within the `lcm()` function:

```
int lcm(int number1,int number2)
{
    return lcm(number2, number1 * number2)/gcd(number1,number2);
}
```

This function will be an infinite recursion because there's no base case. Eventually, you will run into, ironically, a stack overflow problem.

Looking at the nature of the function, I think what you meant is:

```
int lcm(int number1, int number2)
{
    return number1 * number2 / gcd(number1, number2);
}
```